# Terminology Question (ANOVA/t-test) - With and Without Replication?

Tags: anova, spss, excel

Coming from a Psychology background, I have always been taught statistics terms as "within subjects" and "between subjects". Now using excel I see they are using the terms Anova - 2 Factor With Replication and Anova -2 Factor Without Replication. I wanted to get clarification on these to make sure I understand correctly.

Please let me know if this is correct:

- Within Subjects Anova = Without Replication
- Between Subjects Anova = With Replication

Also:

- dependent samples t-test (Within Subjects) = Paired t-test
- Independent samples t-test (Between Subjects) = Two Sample t-test

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, "without replication" doesn't correspond to "within subjects" and "with replication" doesn't correspond to "between subjects."

As I read [the MS Office documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-analysis-toolpak-to-perform-complex-data-analysis-6c67ccf0-f4a9-487c-8dec-bdb5a2cefab6), it suggests that both of the anova analyses in question are between factor designs.

Interestingly, [this tutorial](http://www.statisticshowto.com/perform-two-way-anova-excel-2013-with-replication/) treats both as repeated measures designs.  I think there are other misleading points on this page as well, so I would be cautious about using that page for advice on performing analyses in Excel.